# jquery UI Combobox ONCHANGE not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am trying to use Jquery UI code to make a dropdown box. **I am struggling to understand how to put in an `onchange` event listener so that:**

**(a) the value of the dropdown box is passed to a variable called 'x' and**

**(b) pass the value to an alert function which displays the selected value.**

I have tried using a simple select box with Jquery and it works fine. However I  can't get it to work with more complex code. There is a similar thread to this which has been answered but I still couldnt get it to work with the ui code I am using below. Grateful for any help, and perhaps putting it on Fiddle?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
       <head>
    <title>JQ onchange alert</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


   <style type="text/css">

    .ui-widget {
       font-size: 18px;

    }
    #combobox{
        width: 300px;
    }

     .custom-combobox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    /* support: IE7 */
    *height: 1.7em;
    *top: 0.1em;
    }
.custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
    }


.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 250px; /*Max height of scrollbar*/
    overflow-y: auto;   /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    z-index:1000 !important;
}

</style>


    </head>
    <body>


<div >
    <label>Choose:</label>
    <select id="combobox" onchange="update()">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
        <option value="London">London</option>
        <option value="Rome">Rome</option>
         <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
<option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="C++">C++</option>
<option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
<option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
<option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
<option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
<option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
<option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
<option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
<option value="Java">Java</option>
<option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
<option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
<option value="Perl">Perl</option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="Python">Python</option>
    </select>
</div>


    <script>



    $(function() {
         $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    });


    $( "#combobox" ).change(function() {
    alert( "COMBOBOX ITEM VALUE" );
    });



      (function( $ ) {$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
    _create: function() {this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
            .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
            .insertAfter( this.element );
            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();}
        ,

    _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";


    this.input = $( "<input>" )
    .appendTo( this.wrapper )
    .val( value )
    .attr( "title", "" )
    .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
    .autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 0,
    source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
    })
    .tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"});

    this._on( this.input, {
    autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    this._trigger( "select", event, {
    item: ui.item.option});

    }
    ,



    autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
    });
    },
    _createShowAllButton: function() {
    var input = this.input,
    wasOpen = false;
    $( "<a>" )
    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
    .attr( "title", "Show more" )
    .tooltip()
    .appendTo( this.wrapper )
    .button({
    icons: {
    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
    },
    text: false
    })
    .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
    .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
    .mousedown(function() {
    wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
    })
    .click(function() {
    input.focus();
    // Close if already visible
    if ( wasOpen ) {
    return;
    }
    // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
    });
    },
    _source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
    var text = $( this ).text();
    if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
    return {
    label: text,
    value: text,
    option: this
    };
    }) );
    },
    _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
    // Selected an item, nothing to do
    if ( ui.item ) {
    return;
    }
    // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
    var value = this.input.val(),
    valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
    valid = false;
    this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
    if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
    this.selected = valid = true;
    return false;
    }
    });
    // Found a match, nothing to do
    if ( valid ) {
    return;
    }
    // Remove invalid value
    this.input
    .val( "" )
    .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
    .tooltip( "open" );
    this.element.val( "" );
    this._delay(function() {
    this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
    }, 2500 );
    this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
    },
    _destroy: function() {
    this.wrapper.remove();
    this.element.show();
    }
    });
    })( jQuery );


    </script>

        </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can set a fiddle for us first.. ^^

Comment: Hi sorry, if I can get the update() function to work that would be even better. but it didnt seem to work with the standard js. I guess update() can be anything like function update() {alert(combobox value)} Also tried setting up a fiddle but the css didn't seem to work with it. You can take the whole code and simply put it in browser. it should work with proper css. if you want to see partially working fiddle here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/tokool/wMwsW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/dzVgL/)** of getting the value `onchange` event.

code:

```
 $(function() {

     $( "#combobox" ).selectmenu({
         change: function( event, ui ) {
             console.log(ui);
             var selected_value = ui.item.value;
             alert("You selected : "+selected_value);
         }
     });
});
```

Refer the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change)

**[DEMO with your code !](http://jsfiddle.net/wMwsW/1/)**

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work with the code I pasted above? How can I modify the original code pasted above and make the onchange event work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a link to the demo with your code !

Comment: Thanks where is the link?

Comment: Updated my answer and added the demo link at the bottom ! Or else here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/wMwsW/1/

Comment: Hope you got what you wanted ! Let me know if you still find problems ! Please consider accepting the answer if that helped ! ;)

Comment: Thanks pressed on the link but it doesn't quite work the same as my code. In mine I can click inside the searchbar and type soemthing. However, it doesn't matter 90% there. There is one thing however, how do I use the selected_value variable and use it in a standard js function? what I want to do is execute a normal js function when dropdown menu changes? Many thanks.

Comment: You can take a `global javascript variable` and assign the value of the `selected_value` variable to that global variable and then you can use that variable in another functions also !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57503/discussion-between-user2259146-and-rahul-gupta).

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and provides a much missed link to that event.